# Unable to create download link

Tags: php

I Have an application in which user will log in and user name and his privilege will be set in session variable and login page will include the required home page of the user and user has a option to download the files(pdf,doc,etc....).My problem is when a list of files are listed user clicks a file and it will be in get parameter and file name clicked by the user should be downloadede. . . I cannot create download file because Header is already sent and cannot modify the header ,now how can i create the download link in this scenairo ????

Answer (score 0):

You have to have workaround in your code so that the Header information isn't sent until it's needed. As for download, simply linking a file name should initiate download for it.

Comment: Header will be sent once the user is authenticated and every page user clicks you need to verify whether he is authorized or not. . . so header will be sent under any cost. .  .let me try with output buffering to see the changes. . .